# Spark SQL: datediff won't show results

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Cannot get Spark SQL datediff to work, that is, it runs but won't show results.

I've tried all kinds of approaches, most recently nesting

```
select 
    guid,
    first, 
    last,
    datediff(last_string, first_string)
from (
    select 
        guid,
        first,
        last,
        cast(first as string) as first_string,
        cast(last as string) as last_string
    from (
        select 
            guid, 
            min(entry_date) as first, 
            max(entry_date) as last
        from my_table
        group by guid
    )
)
```

This query works (showing all 4 cols), but add datediff and it only shows 3: guid, first, last

```
select 
    guid,
    first,
    last,
    cast(first as string) as first_string,
    cast(last as string) as last_string
from (
    select 
        guid, 
        min(entry_date) as first, 
        max(entry_date) as last
    from my_table
    group by guid
)
```

**EDIT**: I've verified that datediff works

```
select datediff('2012-12-31', '2011-12-31')
=> 366
```

Comment: Why are you converting (what I assume started as) dates to strings *before* trying to use a function that expects dates?

Comment: what is the date format and data type of entry_date?

Comment: @APH (1) because it didn't work with using dates, and (2) because docs [here](https://docs-snaplogic.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SD/pages/2458071/Date+Functions+and+Properties+Spark+SQL) and [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/functions.html#datediff) suggest the input args are strings.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala they are datetimes (`entry_date    10 non-null datetime64[ns]`), I make them look like `2007-11-28`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to give aliases to the brackets—it may be possible that the highest select can't properly "see" the columns that you expect.

Comment: Aren't I giving alias with using `as` – or am I missing your point?

Comment: Hi, After the brackets for Example
/code select 
    c.guid,
    c.first,
   c. last,
    cast(c.first as string) as first_string,
    cast(c.last as string) as last_string
from (
    select 
        guid, 
        min(entry_date) as first, 
        max(entry_date) as last
    from my_table
    group by guid
) c